# GetProductInfo: Source of information?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012

On Windows Server 2012, where does the function [GetProductInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724358%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) get its information from? From the registry, and if so, from which keys?

Comment: Why do you want to know? It is the/a supported API for obtaining this information. Anything deeper down is likely undocumented and subject to change.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever It's OK if it's just for Windows Server 2012. I want to experiment with changing the values [to get some software to run](http://superuser.com/questions/639786/change-windows-version-numbers). If that breaks the system, no big deal.

Comment: If it's to get some software to run, you should probably be looking at Shims - this is functionality that Microsoft provides that allows a *single* application to be lied to/get legacy behaviours.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks for the suggestion. It's just an installer for an upgrade, though. I assume that I could change the version number, run the installer, and then change it back. The base app already runs fine.